# Unable to import local minikube cluster to rancher on Mac (cattle-cluster-agent fails on :8080/health)

Tags: minikube, rancher

I have installed rancher on Mac, and used custom port numbers; am able to connect to localhost:443 and work through rancher GUI.

```
docker run --privileged -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 980:80 -p 981:443 --name rancher rancher/rancher
```

I then created a minikube local cluster, & tried to import that into rancher via GUI.

```
minikube -p dxmcs3 start
```

As suggested by Rancher as part of GUI, I ran the following to import; since the minikube POD needs to be able to access rancher endpoint on my host machine (mac), I updated the CATTLE_SERVER host to point to https://host.minikube.internal:981 prior to running.

```
curl --insecure -sfL https://localhost:981/v3/import/zsh5mtnkkrtz7tj7scbpb59q5tsjzmhg7r5476z7gdnh4xgjczt7cd_c-6sfj7.yaml | sed 's/https:\/\/localhost:981/https:\/\/host.minikube.internal:981/g' | kubectl apply -f -
```

The deployments go well, but the cluster's import shows up as "pending" forever on Rancher UI.
[image]

on digging, I noticed that the rancher/rancher-agent:v2.5.9 POD fails to start. More specifically, "cluster-register" container fails on health check up start. It tries to to http://(pod-ip):8080/health & fails.

```
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: CATTLE_FEATURES
    - name: CATTLE_IS_RKE
      value: "false"
    - name: CATTLE_SERVER
      value: https://host.minikube.internal:981
    - name: CATTLE_CA_CHECKSUM
      value: d8e8de5d121fac709e414123ff792458931530569555a3d233d555deb62a9490
    - name: CATTLE_CLUSTER
      value: "true"
    - name: CATTLE_K8S_MANAGED
      value: "true"
    - name: CATTLE_CLUSTER_REGISTRY
    image: rancher/rancher-agent:v2.5.9
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: cluster-register
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 2
      periodSeconds: 5
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Appreciate the community's help with resolving this. Or, Any pointer to a page I can refer. I really want to be able to have Rancher manage multiple minikube based local k8s environments for my learning & experimentation.

Comment: How's your setup looks like?
Rancher inside docker and minikube integrated with docker?
I don't understand why your CATTLE_SERVER uses minikube resolver?

Comment: Thanks for looking to help. I have docker desktop on Mac installed, and Rancher is launched as a docker container.  I have minikube deployed with docker as the driving engine for downstream clusters.
I updated the CATTLE_SERVER to point to https://host.minikube.internal:981 since without that, the rancher agent on downstream minikube cluster was not able to reach the rancher server on docker.

Comment: I tried on Azure cloud as an alternative to unblock myself, and ran into same issue; the /health readiness probe on pod/cattle-cluster-agent fails. This is the similar issue I had on local minikube.  

1. Created one AKS#1 (Azure Managed K8S) cluster, and deployed Rancher into it. 
2. Created a second AKS#2 cluster as downstream cluster & tried to import that into the rancher instance.
3. Import itself was done by accessing the Rancher app from AKS#1 on my Mac, and running the Rancher provided kubectl commands against AKS#2, with admin kubeconfig.

Appreciate help resolving this.

Comment: You should see the pod logs of the cattle-agent, because the probe status doesn't tell why it won't run.

From the top of my head, you can try things like this:


1.  I still suspect it's a resolver issue. Get your physical IP address (from wifi or ethernet). Access Rancher using this. Set the "server-url" in Rancher Settings using this IP. Use the same IP in CATTLE_SERVER parameter.


2. For the AKS setup, make sure any pod in AKS#2 can reach AKS#1. At the very least, AKS#1 Rancher URL must be reachable over public internet.